# Open URL with inputs in VB?

Tags: vb.net, url

I have a problem with vb.net which I find kinda weird.

So I have this sub called NavigationWebURL which opens any url in your default browser.

```
NavigateWebURL("http://URLHERE.net/private.php?action=send&uid=2763296&subject=Application rating&message=I rate your Riptide application " + MetroTrackBar1.Value + " out of 100", "default")
```

But that gives me following error message:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried "&" instead of "+" to concatenate your text? Or even a cast on your trackbar value, like CStr(MetroTrackBar1.Value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is one of the very good reasons to why you should ***never*** use the plus sign (`+`) to concatenate strings.

When you're concatenating strings with the plus sign and you include a number (Integer, Long, Double, Decimal, etc.) the compiler tries to add all the entries together as if the whole thing was a number.

Visual Basic has it's own concatenation operator (`&`), which in my opinion should always be used with strings to avoid problems.

`MetroTrackBar1.Value` is of a numeric type, which is why you get the error. To fix it, just replace the plus signs with concatenation operators.

```
NavigateWebURL("http://URLHERE.net/private.php?action=send&uid=2763296&subject=Application rating&message=I rate your Riptide application " & MetroTrackBar1.Value & " out of 100", "default")
```